# Excel formula to match two columns and use sum function to subtract corresponding values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvJEl.jpg)

The formula should lookup value from column A in column D and then the corresponding values should be subtracted in G1 and so on.

thanks.

Comment: Wanna show some effort?

Comment: I tried using the sumproduct and vlookup functions however this only add the columns I need to subtract not to mention as well that column B needs to be placed after column d for the vlookup to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=$B1-VLOOKUP($A1,$D:$E,2,0)
```